# Where to put JQuery Themeroller files in Rails app? (No change in view)

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I downloaded the zip file containing the custom theme from JQuery Mobile Themeroller website.

The zip contains:

---

**Themes Directory** (below is what is inside this directory)

- Images Directory
  Example.css
  Example.min.css

**Index.html (just instructions I think)**

---

I can't figure out where to put the css files and image directory to make the theme work.

I tried putting them in app/assets/stylesheets and public/stylesheets, yet my page doesn't change to match the theme.

Maybe I'm not referencing the pages correctly.

```
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Example.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization)

So you need to put it inside `vendor/assets` and include it inside`app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
*= Example.min
```

or

```
*= Example
```

Comment: Do I need to change any of the html that I posted?

Comment: You can remove it from `<head>` after.